# Automatic Weight problem

Tags: armature, weight-painting, parent

I want to parent my character's pants to the armature, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *With Automatic Weights*, but there's a problem with the pants after doing so.

What I tried so far:
Removed doubles, Recalculate normals, clear sharp and also by manually painting weights. But when I brush weights, it still produces same results.

By the way I'm using Blender 2.77a

[image: Edit mode]
[image: before parenting]
[image: This what happens]

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: The armature is not in rest pose when you are parenting. You should ctrl+A then apply pose as rest pose.

Comment: oh didn't see your comment earlier, @lemon , so I should model the pants, and align it by the armatures rest pose...I'm gonna try that out...

Comment: You can keep the pants in place, but apply pose as rest pose to the armature placed along the pants. This can be done on the select bones (in pose mode)

Comment: Oh, I do it the other way though, and it works!Thank you @lemon

Comment: I recognize that this problem is probably long solved, but I'm voting to close the question on the basis of "needs details"-- we can't tell you what's wrong without being able to inspect the file.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, there was a question like this. You should try to rearrange the modifier stack, I'm pretty sure that's the problem. (or give us a screenshot of the stack if you are not sure how it should go)

Comment: ok, thank you for helping, @BumbleBee, for the pants, it only contains the armature modifier, but for the armature itself, wait? armature can't have modifiers right?

Comment: @amiel, no, not armatures atleast I know not the sort that a mesh can(ex: subsurf).

Comment: @amiel, you should probably upload the .blend